# Locating element in splinter/selenium that require scroll

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, webautomation, splinter

I am trying to locate an input field that comes in view after scrolling(horizontally), when i am trying to access it without scrolling, the error is "Element is not interactable".

```
release_level_edit = browser.find_by_xpath(
                '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[107]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')
release_level_edit.fill('Inserted')
release_level_edit.type('\ue007')
```

However when if i am using Action.move_by_offset() the error is move target out of bounds, here is the code

```
while True:
    try:
        release_level_edit = browser.find_by_xpath(
            '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[107]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')
        release_level_edit.fill('Inserted')
        release_level_edit.type('\ue007')
        break
    except Exception:
        action_chains = ActionChains(browser.driver)
        action_chains.move_by_offset(50, 0)
        action_chains.perform()
```

EDIT: Here is html code of the element-

```
<input id="combobox-9822-inputEl" data-ref="inputEl" type="text" size="1" name="combobox-9822-inputEl" placeholder="Inserted" style="text-align:left;" aria-hidden="false" aria-disabled="false" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="combobox-9822-inputEl combobox-9822-picker-listEl" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-invalid="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-describedby="combobox-9822-ariaStatusEl" aria-required="false" class="x-form-field x-form-empty-field x-form-empty-field-default x-form-text x-form-text-default " autocomplete="off" data-componentid="combobox-9822">
```

Here is the html for scrollbar:

```
<div class="x-grid-scrollbar  x-scroller x-grid-scrollbar-visible" id="ext-element-38" style="overflow: scroll hidden; width: 749px; height: 17px; left: 0px;"><div class="x-scroller-spacer" role="presentation" id="ext-element-44" style="transform: translate3d(9623px, 0px, 0px); line-height: 1px;"></div></div>
```

What should i do?

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML of the element.

Comment: Html code added, also i have tried javascript execute for horizontal scroll, doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This trick worked:**

```
scroll = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,xpath)        
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element
(scroll).click(scroll).perform()
```

*Just click the scrollbar,it takes you to the end of the page and then you can access the element.
p.s: This is just a work around.*